# How to hide fields when radio button is selected with jquery in Prestashop checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, prestashop

What i have: 2 radio buttons and several fields.

What i want:
- When radio button "delivery to address" to SHOW: addres1, postcode and city - and hide id_state field.
- When other button is selected "delivery to carrier office" is selected to hide fields: address1, postcode and city - but to show id_state (i use it for select carrier offices)

I use several .tpl files in checkout page that showing this radio buttons. Radio buttons are get from order-carrier.tpl file:

```
<div class="delivery_options">
        {foreach $option_list as $key => $option}
            <div class="delivery_option {if ($option@index % 2)}alternate_{/if}item">
                <input class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[{$id_address}]" onchange="{if $opc}updateCarrierSelectionAndGift();{else}updateExtraCarrier('{$key}', {$id_address});{/if}" id="delivery_option_{$id_address}_{$option@index}" value="{$key}" {if isset($delivery_option[$id_address]) && $delivery_option[$id_address] == $key}checked="checked"{/if} />
                <label for="delivery_option_{$id_address}_{$option@index}">
                    <table class="resume">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="delivery_option_logo">
                                {foreach $option.carrier_list as $carrier}
                                    {if $carrier.logo}
                                        <img src="{$carrier.logo}" alt="{$carrier.instance->name}"/>
                                    {else if !$option.unique_carrier}
                                        {$carrier.instance->name}
                                        {if !$carrier@last} - {/if}
                                    {/if}
                                {/foreach}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            {if $option.unique_carrier}
                                {foreach $option.carrier_list as $carrier}
                                    <div class="delivery_option_title">{$carrier.instance->name}</div>
                                {/foreach}
                                {if isset($carrier.instance->delay[$cookie->id_lang])}
                                    <div class="delivery_option_delay">{$carrier.instance->delay[$cookie->id_lang]}</div>
                                {/if}
                            {/if}
                            {if count($option_list) > 1}
                                {if $option.is_best_grade}
                                    {if $option.is_best_price}
                                    <div class="delivery_option_best delivery_option_icon">{l s='The best price and speed'}</div>
                                    {else}
                                    <div class="delivery_option_fast delivery_option_icon">{l s='The fastest'}</div>
                                    {/if}
                                {else}
                                    {if $option.is_best_price}
                                    <div class="delivery_option_best_price delivery_option_icon">{l s='The best price'}</div>
                                    {/if}
                                {/if}
                            {/if}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="delivery_option_price">
                                {if $option.total_price_with_tax && (!isset($free_shipping) || (isset($free_shipping) && !$free_shipping))}

                                    {if $use_taxes == 1}
                                        {if $priceDisplay == 1}
                                            {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_without_tax} {l s='(tax excl.)'}
                                        {else}
                                            {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_with_tax} {l s='(tax incl.)'}
                                        {/if}
                                    {/if}
                                {else}
                                    {l s='Free'}
                                {/if}
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="delivery_option_carrier {if isset($delivery_option[$id_address]) && $delivery_option[$id_address] == $key}selected{/if} {if $option.unique_carrier}not-displayable{/if}">
                        {foreach $option.carrier_list as $carrier}
                        <tr>
                            {if !$option.unique_carrier}
                            <td class="first_item">
                            <input type="hidden" value="{$carrier.instance->id}" name="id_carrier" />
                                {if $carrier.logo}
                                    <img src="{$carrier.logo}" alt="{$carrier.instance->name}"/>
                                {/if}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {$carrier.instance->name}
                            </td>
                            {/if}
                            <td {if $option.unique_carrier}class="first_item" colspan="2"{/if}>
                                <input type="hidden" value="{$carrier.instance->id}" name="id_carrier" />
                                {if isset($carrier.instance->delay[$cookie->id_lang])}
                                    {$carrier.instance->delay[$cookie->id_lang]}<br />
                                    {if count($carrier.product_list) <= 1}
                                        ({l s='Product concerned:'}
                                    {else}
                                        ({l s='Products concerned:'}
                                    {/if}
                                    {* This foreach is on one line, to avoid tabulation in the title attribute of the acronym *}
                                    {foreach $carrier.product_list as $product}
                                    {if $product@index == 4}<acronym title="{/if}{if $product@index >= 4}{$product.name}{if isset($product.attributes) && $product.attributes} {$product.attributes|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{/if}{if !$product@last}, {else}">...</acronym>){/if}{else}{$product.name}{if isset($product.attributes) && $product.attributes} {$product.attributes|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{/if}{if !$product@last}, {else}){/if}{/if}{/foreach}
                                {/if}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {/foreach}
                    </table>
                </label>
            </div>
```

And fields are from order-opc-new-account.tpl:

```
<p class="text">
                <label for="company">{l s='Company'}</label>
                <input type="text" class="text" id="company" name="company" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.company}{$guestInformations.company}{/if}" />
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "vat_number"}    
            <div id="vat_number_block" style="display:none;">
                <p class="text">
                    <label for="vat_number">{l s='VAT number'}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="vat_number" id="vat_number" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.vat_number}{$guestInformations.vat_number}{/if}" />
                </p>
            </div>
            {elseif $field_name eq "dni"}
            {assign var='dniExist' value=true}
            <p class="text">
                <label for="dni">{l s='Identification number'}</label>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="dni" id="dni" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.dni}{$guestInformations.dni}{/if}" />
                <span class="form_info">{l s='DNI / NIF / NIE'}</span>
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "firstname"}
            <p class="required text">
                <label for="firstname">{l s=''}</label>
                <input type="text" class="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.firstname}{$guestInformations.firstname}{/if}" placeholder="Име" required />
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "lastname"}
            <p class="required text">
                <label for="lastname">{l s=''}</label>
                <input type="text" class="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.lastname}{$guestInformations.lastname}{/if}" placeholder="Фамилия" required />
            </p>
            <p class="{if isset($one_phone_at_least) && $one_phone_at_least}required {/if}text">
                <label for="phone_mobile">{l s=''}{if isset($one_phone_at_least) && $one_phone_at_least}{/if}</label>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="phone_mobile" id="phone_mobile" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.phone_mobile}{$guestInformations.phone_mobile}{/if}" placeholder="Телефон" required />
                <span class="form_hint">Въведи коректен телефон номер, на който може да те потърсим относно поръчката!</span>
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "postcode"}
            {$postCodeExist = true}
            <p class="required postcode text" style="display:none">
                <label for="postcode">{l s=''}</label>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.postcode}{$guestInformations.postcode}{/if}" onkeyup="$('#postcode').val($('#postcode').val().toUpperCase());" placeholder="Пощенски код" required />
                <span class="form_hint">Въведи четири цифрения пощенски код на твоето населено място.</span>
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "city"}
            <p class="required text">
                <label for="city">{l s=''} </label>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="city" id="city" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.city}{$guestInformations.city}{/if}" placeholder="Град/Село" required />
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "address1"}
            <p class="required text">
                <label for="address1">{l s=''} </label>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.address1}{$guestInformations.address1}{/if}" placeholder="кв./ бул./ ул./ №/ ет./ ап." required />
                <span class="form_hint">Ако желаеш доставка до адрес, упъти ни къде точно да доставим пратката ти. Ако желаеш да получиш поръчката си по-бързо и евтино, напиши тук офиса на Еконт в твоя град и вземи пратката си от там - виж помощната информация в дясно и научи дали има офис на Еконт в твоя град.</span>
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "country" || $field_name eq "Country:name"}
            <p class="required select">
                <label for="id_country">{l s=''}</label>
                <select name="id_country" id="id_country" placeholder="Изберете офис">
                    {foreach from=$countries item=v}
                    <option value="{$v.id_country}"{if (isset($guestInformations) AND $guestInformations.id_country == $v.id_country) OR (!isset($guestInformations) && $sl_country == $v.id_country)} selected="selected"{/if}>{$v.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</option>
                    {/foreach}
                </select>
            </p>
            {elseif $field_name eq "state" || $field_name eq 'State:name'}
            {$stateExist = true}
            <p class="required id_state select" style="display:none;">
                <label for="id_state">{l s=''}</label>
                <select name="id_state" id="id_state">
                    <option value="">-</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            {/if}
            {/foreach}
            {if !$postCodeExist}
            <p class="required postcode text hidden">
                <label for="postcode">{l s='Zip / Postal code'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.postcode}{$guestInformations.postcode}{/if}" onkeyup="$('#postcode').val($('#postcode').val().toUpperCase());" />
            </p>
            {/if}               
            {if !$stateExist}
            <p class="required id_state select hidden">
                <label for="id_state">{l s=''}</label>
                <select name="id_state" id="id_state">
                    <option value="">-</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            {/if}
            {if !$dniExist}
            <p class="required text dni">
                <label for="dni">{l s='Identification number'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="dni" id="dni" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.dni}{$guestInformations.dni}{/if}" />
                <span class="form_info">{l s='DNI / NIF / NIE'}</span>
            </p>
            {/if}
            <input type="hidden" name="alias" id="alias" value="{l s='My address'}"/>

            <div id="opc_invoice_address" class="is_customer_param">
                {assign var=stateExist value=false}
                {assign var=postCodeExist value=false}
                {assign var=dniExist value=false}
                <h3>{l s='Invoice address'}</h3>
                {foreach from=$inv_all_fields item=field_name}
                {if $field_name eq "company" &&  $b2b_enable}
                <p class="text">
                    <label for="company_invoice">{l s='Company'}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" id="company_invoice" name="company_invoice" value="" />
                </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "vat_number"}
                <div id="vat_number_block_invoice" class="is_customer_param" style="display:none;">
                    <p class="text">
                        <label for="vat_number_invoice">{l s='VAT number'}</label>
                        <input type="text" class="text" id="vat_number_invoice" name="vat_number_invoice" value="" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                {elseif $field_name eq "dni"}
                {assign var='dniExist' value=true}
                <p class="text">
                    <label for="dni_invoice">{l s='Identification number'}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="dni_invoice" id="dni_invoice" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.dni_invoice}{$guestInformations.dni_invoice}{/if}" />
                    <span class="form_info">{l s='DNI / NIF / NIE'}</span>
                </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "firstname"}
                <p class="required text">
                    <label for="firstname_invoice">{l s='First name'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" id="firstname_invoice" name="firstname_invoice" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.firstname_invoice}{$guestInformations.firstname_invoice}{/if}" />
                </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "lastname"}
                <p class="required text">
                    <label for="lastname_invoice">{l s='Last name'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" id="lastname_invoice" name="lastname_invoice" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.lastname_invoice}{$guestInformations.lastname_invoice}{/if}" />
                </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "address1"}
                <p class="required text">
                    <label for="address1_invoice">{l s='Address'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="address1_invoice" id="address1_invoice" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.address1_invoice}{$guestInformations.address1_invoice}{/if}" />
                </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "address2"}
                <p class="text is_customer_param">
                    <label for="address2_invoice">{l s='Address (Line 2)'}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="address2_invoice" id="address2_invoice" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.address2_invoice}{$guestInformations.address2_invoice}{/if}" />
                </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "postcode"}
                {$postCodeExist = true}
                <p class="required postcode_invoice text">
                    <label for="postcode_invoice">{l s='Zip / Postal Code'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="postcode_invoice" id="postcode_invoice" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.postcode_invoice}{$guestInformations.postcode_invoice}{/if}" onkeyup="$('#postcode_invoice').val($('#postcode_invoice').val().toUpperCase());" />
                </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "city"}
                <p class="required text">
                    <label for="city_invoice">{l s='City'} <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="city_invoice" id="city_invoice" value="{if isset($guestInformations) && $guestInformations.city_invoice}{$guestInformations.city_invoice}{/if}" />
                </p>
```

@Brian correct my code and now working but after several changes of radio button stop working - or working only at first change why?

```
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    toggleFields();

                    $('.delivery_option_radio').on('change', function() {
                        toggleFields();
                    });
                });

                function toggleFields() {
                    if ($('#delivery_option_0_0').is(':checked')) {
                        $('#address1').show();
                        $('#postcode').show();
                        $('#city').show();
                        $('#id_state').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#address1').hide();
                        $('#postcode').hide();
                        $('#city').hide();
                        $('#id_state').show();
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

You can test live page at: test.detelinmarkov.com/quick-order
(first you need to add something in cart)

P.s: I try to hide it with pure css but not working.

Comment: Take a look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ngaK8/). Since you didn't include all your code, it won't necessarily match up exactly, but is this what you're trying to accomplish? If that is what you are looking for, I'll add it as an answer and explain more.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Comment: @Brian Now working but only on first change. When i change from delivery_option_0_0 to other radio option (delivery_option_0_1) one field is hide but when i again go to delivery_option_0_0 nothing happend! You can see it in my test shop: test.delinmarkov.com/quick-order -> you need to add something in cart first.

Now i edit post and add whole code.

Thank you for your comment and help!

Answer (score 0):

i know your problem, the delivery radios is generated by ajax, so you need to attache your script to refresh every ajax call.

sorry for my english : )